# How to prioritize packages installed from files in APT?

Tags: apt, dpkg, priority

I want to have packages installed manually via `dpkg -i` not being updated.
I figured the most elegant way to do this would to pin them to a high priority.

The manpage of `apt_preferences` says

> Assign [...] priority 990 to the instances that are not installed and belong to the target release.

so I guess it should be higher than that.

Also:

> For example, the following record causes APT to
>            assign a high priority to all package instances  available  from  the
>            local site.

```
     Package: *
     Pin: origin ""
     Pin-Priority: 999
```

But even with priority 1100 it doesn't work.

How can I prevent such packages (edit) from being updated by `apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool you are looking for to complete your task is `apt-mark`.

Use the following command to mark a manually installed `[Package]` to prevent `apt` from updating it.

```
apt-mark hold [Package]
```

The command marks the package as *held*. A held package cannot be installed, upgraded, removed, or purged.

You can "unhold" a package with `apt-mark unhold [Package]` if you need to remove it.

Please check out the `apt-mark` [manpage](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man8/apt-mark.8.html) for more information on these tools.

Comment: I new of that possibility, but isn't there a way to generally prefer locally installed packages, regardless of version number? Having to deal with every individual package doesn't seem to be a good solution to me, especially since I consider it quiet a common use case to prefer packages installed from files.

Comment: @philipp2100 I can look into a more robust solution. As far as I can tell you were doing things correctly, using `apt-mark` is to guarantee that `apt` does not do anything with the package in question.

Comment: @philipp2100 If you choose to use `apt_preferences` and assign a pin priority you need to make sure that your local package source is listed at the top of `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/153408) on AskUbuntu. It looks like you will need to create a local repo and reference that. If necessary I can update my answer if you can update your post with what version of Debian or Debian-based Linux you are running.

Comment: @philipp2100 I have also found [this manual page](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#listofnotablepinpinningtechnique) with a table explaining priorities. If I am reading it correctly, it looks like assigning a pin priority of -1 accomplishes a similar goal as `apt-mark hold`.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! It's unfortunate that you can seem to assign a pin priority to a "file" source and would have to create a local repo. If this is indeed not possible you don't have to update your answer. Otherwise I can include my distribution in the question. It's Devuan Ascii.

Comment: @philipp2100 you can put all the deb files you need to manage this way in a directory and reference that in your sources.list as pointed out in [the AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/a/153408) that I previously linked. If you would like those steps outlined here I can change the answer to suit that.

Comment: I tried it and found that creating a directory with the files is not enough. You still have to 1. set the `apt_preferences` and 2. create a `packages` and 3. a `Release` file (or state `[trusted=yes]` in your `sources.list`). 4., you have to keep these files (at least the `packages` file) unchanged in this directory, otherwise your packages may be upgraded as soon as they are not in this repository anymore. This may still be a preferable solution, so I think you should add it to your answer, and link to a (new) question explaining all these steps. I can also add a new answer doing that.

Comment: @philipp2100 I would suggest you post your own answer with the exact steps you took and accept that if that is the solution that works best for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I sticked with `apt-mark hold`, so we can leave it as is.